# How to convert QImage format to format supported by OpenGL

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, qt4

I'm using `QImage` to load images which then used as textures in OpenGL.
The problem is that color components have different order in `QImage` and OpenGL.
Currently I'm using `GL_RGBA` format in OpenGL and `QImage::Format_ARGB32` in Qt.
Because of that, I have to manually swap bytes for each pixel of loaded image, before creating a texture in OpenGL. Moreover, to swap bytes correctly I need to know endianness of a machine.

Does anyone know a better solution for this? At least, is there any way to make this conversion endianness-independent?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The last three parameters to `glTex(Sub)Image` define how the [pixel transfer to OpenGL](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Pixel_Transfer#Pixel_transfer_arguments) takes place. If you have 4 8-bit values, sequentially, in the ARGB order, then I would suggest the following:

```
glTexImage2D(..., GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8_REV, *);
```

To deal with endian conversion issues, use `glPixelStore` parameters. Specifically, `GL_UNPACK_SWAP_BYTES`. The above is designed for little-endian machines, so if you're on a big-endian machine you should call `glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_SWAP_BYTES, GL_TRUE);` before calling this function, and then set it back to `GL_FALSE` afterwards.

---

Note: I know you didn't mention it, but in case you're considering mobile platforms, remember that OpenGL ES is **not** OpenGL. Desktop OpenGL requires implementations to be able to handle a wide variety of pixel arrangements in transfer operations. GL ES mandates almost the opposite. The pixel transfer formats must *exactly* match the internal format of the texture. So if you were doing GL ES development, you would have to do the byte swapping on your own.